# Finding the ratio of time spent at one of two rates with the distance formula.

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-modeling

I am not sure how this falls on the question about homework questions because technically this is a homework question however I am not a student just a learner trying to reacquaint myself with college algebra.

The chapter covers modeling and the specific questions gives four constants.  A total distance of $70$mi, a total time of $4.5$ hours and two rates of speed $20$ mi/h and $12$ mi/h and the question is to find what was the amount of distance traveled at $20$ mi/h.

Really, I am not sure, where to begin.Please help

Comment: As with all word problems, define variables and write equations to represent what you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the system of equations (for the total distance and for the  total time)
$$
S = S_1 + S_2,
$$
where $S$ is the total distance and $S_1$, $S_2$ are distances traveled with velocities $v_1$, $v_2$ respectively.
Now the time
$$
t = t_1 + t_2 = S_1/v_1 + S_2/v_2,
$$ 
where $t$ is the total time and $t_1 = S_1/v_1$, $t_2 = S_2/v_2$ are times spent travelling with velocities $v_1$, $v_2$ respectively.
Now just solve this $2$ equations for $S_1$, $S_2$ and you'll get the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I am rusty still and I knew I needed to create a system of equations but wasn't sure which set of equations.